# Why does my keras-contrib's crf.accuracy increase so fast?

Tags: keras, crf

I use BiLSTM+CRF to do a sequence tagging model for postagging. But I find my crf.accuracy increases so fast and reach 1.0 just in the first epoch.
I use CRF layer from keras_contrib lib, and write code referring to the CRF example. My backend is Tensorflow.

        `output = TimeDistributed(Dense(100,activation='relu'),name='Dense_1')(lstm_output)
        output = Dropout(rate=0.3)(output)
        if self.use_crf:
            crf_layer = CRF(self.label_num,sparse_target=True)
            output = crf_layer(output)
            model = Model(inputs, output)
            model.compile('adam', loss=crf_layer.loss_function, metrics=[crf_layer.accuracy])
        else:
            output = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.label_num,activation='softmax'), name='Dense_2')(output)
            model = Model(inputs, output)
            model.compile('adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`

but the crf_layer.accuracy seems to increase so fast. In the first epoch, it shows as

1888/2000 [===========================>..] - ETA: 4s - loss: 17.2046 - acc: 0.9666
 1920/2000 [===========================>..] - ETA: 3s - loss: 17.1906 - acc: 0.9671
 1952/2000 [============================>.] - ETA: 2s - loss: 17.2806 - acc: 0.9677
 1984/2000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 17.2222 - acc: 0.9682

But the accuracyis is just 0.4 if I don't use CRF, just like the code in else part, and the training looks more normal.

So whether I ignore some details in keras_contrib's CRF

Answer (score 1):

I find the bug. Because my target is a one-hot vector, I can't set sparse_target=True. After I fix this, it looks normal now.